# Why was this post blocked

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, recommendation-questions

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820329/how-to-select-different-geography-classes) did ask for a recommendation for a library but I gave the context for my question so that it was not asking for opinion but rather for which of the libraries I cited was the right one to use.  I believe that made it a valid question and hereby object to the blockage.

I have rewritten it.  I hope you allow it given this explanation.

Answer (score 14):

It didn't get blocked; it got closed.  The close message reads "This question does not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers."

Unfortunately, the close reason links to the wrong article.  The correct one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Item 4 in this article reads:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

The last paragraph in your question is very specific about asking for a recommendation.  It says:

> Which library should be used so that my application and SQL Server are compatible?

The problem is not the nature of your recommendation request.  Your question should be asking about the compatibility problem itself, not which library to use to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have a library problem. You have a programming problem. You say so in your question:

> I tried using DbGeography using System.Spatial but the properties and methods available for that type don't match the documentation here.

Had you shared the minimal code demonstrating where you're stuck and the the SQL Schema you plan to use it with, that might be a fun  question to answer. Specially if looking at the documentation tells me that class you' think you're using lives in a namespace System.Data.Spatial that comes in the assembly System.Data.Entity.dll. You didn't mention that you found that dll, so it doesn't add up. It is much easier to have us reason [about actual code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (that we can compile and run) and the task you want to achieve. Also future visitors find that much easier to relate to and value your question.

Answers to a question with code and a single problem statement either solve your problem or suggest viable alternatives. You don't need a library, you need a solution to resolve the coding problem you currently face. That might be solved by using a different Type from a different assembly. But that is not what have to  ask for, those libraries come from the answers (when they are valid alternatives).

Answer (score 3):

> ...but I gave the context for my question so that it was not asking for opinion...

This is an unfortunately common argument for individual find/recommendation posts. I think it comes from a misreading of the closure text. It clearly states that all questions of this type are off-topic:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic...

and then explains why:

> ...they **tend to** attract opinionated answers and spam.

Emphasis added. The close reason does not state that only questions that get these kinds of answers are off topic, it only says that they often do. But all of them are off-topic. We don't handle these on a case-by-case basis where we try to guess which questions will cause problems and which won't.